# Difference between "ability" and "capability"

Tags: differences, synonyms, nouns

What is the difference in usage between *ability* and *capability*?

Comment: On my side, I think these two words are synonyms, since they have the same sense.

Comment: [Ability vs. capability vs. capacity](http://grammarist.com/usage/ability-capability-capacity/) on Grammarist

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Capability implies unrealised potential, as in "John is capable of winning", which implies John has the ability to win but it's not definite. It means more or less "John has the talent that's needed to win."

Ability, on the other hand, implies possibility. "John is able to win" means John is in the running to win but not necessarily that he has the skills or ability to win. It means more or less "It's possible that John will win".

But here's where it gets more confusing:

"John is able to read" means John can read without doubt, whereas "John is capable of reading" means John has all the necessary brain power and whatnot to be able to read but the question of whether or not he can read at the moment is left unsaid (although the fact that someone does say "John is capable of reading" probably means John can't read right now).

Comment: I disagree. "John is capable of reading" does not imply that John can't read at the moment.

Comment: So, "capability" means a talent that someone was born with to do something and "ability" means that some one got some skill to do something, right?

Comment: The "cap-" on "capable" comes from the latin "capere," to grasp or take. So "John is capable of reading" does mean more accurately "John is able to learn to read" or rather "John is able to grasp the skill of reading," not, however, that he IS able to read.

Comment: The etymology of a word does not necessarily have anything to do with its modern meaning. Again, saying that someone is capable of x does not imply that they cannot do x right now. That is simply false.

Comment: Another good example might be: all nations at the World Cup are able to win (in the sense that it's possible), while only a few are realistically capable of winning (i.e. have the necessary skills to do so).

Alternatively: Kobe Bryant is able to slam dunk a basketball, while John, my very tall friend, is capable of slam dunking a basketball (which implies he can't slam dunk a basketball at the moment).

Comment: From the OED entry for able, note the last word used in the definition: "b. In predicative use, with infinitive or without complement: having the means, capacity, or qualifications to do something; having sufficient power; in such a position that a particular action is possible; worthy, qualified, competent, capable."

Comment: Alan, I'm saying that if someone, John for instance, is capable of doing x, that does not imply that John can do x right now. Whether John can or cannot do x right now is left unsaid.

Comment: And Alan, I've realised the wording in the original definition I put up wasn't accurate. Now edited.

Comment: I think the problem here is that we need to distinguish between denotation and connotation. Yes, there probably is sometimes a rather subtle connotation for "capable" which suggests that it is less strong in some sense than "able". But I think even this is highly variable. This is one of the things which makes lexical semantics so "fun". :)

Comment: Let's try something like this.

(1) John is capable of reading, but he is currently illiterate.

(2) John is able to read, but he is currently illiterate

How do those sound to people? I think the distinction is very subtle and not a matter of denotation...

Comment: And I would say number 2 is contradictory.

Comment: But it does not follow that "capable" implies the lack of present ability. Rather that "able" does imply this, whereas "capable" does not. This is not the same thing as saying that "capable" actually means "not presently able".

Comment: I think people that are saying that capable implies that the entity has a inherent capability that they do not possess "right now" and missing the point. There is no implication either way. It is left unsaid and unexplored. That's the beauty of the word.

Comment: I don't feel that capability should necessarily indicate a limitation in a person. Might a person be equally capable of two challenging pursuits and choose one versus the other? E.g., "She was capable of traversing either the river or the mountain, but chose the mountain."

Comment: I'm a little late to the game here but I came across this question via Google. I suggest that "capability" is along the same lines of the "cap-of-ability". By this I mean that 'John has the capability to do x' suggests that the "cap" (limit) on John's ability allows him to do x. Whether John is ABLE to do it right now (ie, current 'ability') is left unstated, as is whether John may have the 'ability' to go above/beyond this, thus is unknown. To reiterate/summarise - IMO, capability refers to potential ability while ability refers to what is able to be done now.

Answer (score 7):

If we would like to describe the functionality of a specific product like a software, I think it is more common to use 'capabilities' (vs 'abilities'): "MS Word has these capabilities: edit tables, copy and past, styles etc."

Comment: There are some interesting answers to this question. My understanding of the two words is that "capability" implies having the tools or physical attributes to perform a task while "ability" implies having the skills or training to perform a task. I think this means that my usage coincides with Sarhanis' description and not Alan Hogue's. It also means that you are correct: software has capabilities, not abilities.

Answer (score 3):

There's another shade of meaning not yet touched upon. *able* can also be of things, "of a thing (esp. a boat): strong, substantial, well built; or a person who is intelligent, skillful, apt, talented, or clever (OED). Compare, "It is an able ship/It is a capable ship." They are both meaningful, but I would be more likely to use the first one. Another example, "She is an able tour guide/she is a capable tour guide". The second sounds contrived to me, even a little damning.

It's also interesting to note that they entered English through different sources, and that *able* is the older of the two.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here, (now balanced with an up.) @Charlie's comments ring true to this native (US) speaker.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, these are very nearly perfect synonyms.

Comment: interesting point, I've always thought of them as being distinctively different and used them in differing contexts. But the more I think about it the more I probably could be switching each for the other.

Answer (score 2):

I want to give only one condense sentence, so that you can easily to remember.

## *Capability* often refers to extremes of *ability*.

> I have the ability to write, but I don’t have the capability to write a novel.

<sub>[Ability vs. capability vs. capacity](http://grammarist.com/usage/ability-capability-capacity/) on Grammarist</sub>